# MonoDroid device registeration for push notifications using PushSharp

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

In my monodroid application I have a problem registering some devices for push notifications using pushSharp. My general push notification setup works fine on newer devices such as SGS2, SGS3 and Nexus7, however on Legend and Hero running 2.2 and 2.2.1 the registration fails in release (works fine in debug).
I have narrowed down the problem to the StartService call:

```
var intent = new Intent(GCMConstants.INTENT_TO_GCM_REGISTRATION);
intent.SetPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
intent.PutExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
                PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
intent.PutExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_SENDER, senders);
context.StartService(intent);
```

The manifest file looks fine:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
<!-- Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for push messages -->
<permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

The intent looks fine (act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf) and the senderId is correct, but the GCMIntentService OnReceive method is never triggered...

Sometimes the following error message can be seen using logcat (although not consistently):

```
E/C2DMRegistrar(  302): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught java.io.IOException: SSL shutdown failed: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe.
```

I am not really sure how to solve this problem and would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Tried setting linking to none in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need these permissions as they should be set within your pushsharp code...

```
    <permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```